# The custom fonts not being displayed in Macos Cocoa application

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am trying to include a set of fonts to the new mac app. The fonts are installed in my system so it's displaying properly. 
But if I create an archive and distribute it to people without the fonts installed, the fonts are not being displayed.

1) Added fonts to the folder Fonts.

[image]

2)  Added the fonts with fonts being the subpath
[image]

3) Added references to all the fonts to info Plist file:
[image]

Removed 'Fonts provided by application' in an alternate build as it was an Ios only information. Still no luck.

4) I checked and confirm that the fonts are present inside the 'Fonts ' directory inside the application package after archiving.

But the application does not display the fonts bundled for some reason.

Please advise how to proceed further.